# Manually Generating Rails Cache Key

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use isolated workers to build and manipulate my cache. I would like to keep these workers as lean as possible. (don't use rails)

**I'm having difficulty forging rails generated cache keys**

In my view I have this:

```
cache ["comments", @ama]
```

I'm trying to replicate the key that it produces with the following:

```
updated_at = Time.parse(row['updated_at'])
timestamp = updated_at.utc.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
cache_key = "views/comments/amas/#{row['id']}-#{timestamp}"
```

Which will produce:

```
views/comments/amas/432-20121227010114
```

The cache from that key is blank.

Either I'm not formatting my key correctly, or the cache is missing. I'm 95% confident the cache i'm seeking is there.

*(I'm able to push cache with a key such as 'test', and then get it back. So I know the caching is working)*

Helpful References:

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/cache_key
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Time/Conversions

Helpful Information:

- The cache server isn't local, and yes I'm pointing to it.
- Even if the key didn't exist, When I load the page in production the key & cache would be built on the spot. Which I have tried.
- using Rails 4.0.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

template cache keys look like this:

```
views/projects/123-20120806214154/7a1156131a6928cb0026877f8b749ac9
       ^class   ^id ^updated_at    ^template tree digest
```

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper.html#method-i-cache

Comment: How does one generate this key?

Comment: In views the `cache` method does this automatically by calling `cache_key` on records or relations, e.g. `cache ['sidebar', @comments]` is the same as `cache ['sidebar', @comments.cache_key]`. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Integration.html#method-i-cache_key

Answer (score 7):

The most efficient way to implement low-level caching is using the Rails.cache.fetch method. It will read a value from the cache if it available; otherwise it will execute a block passed to it and return the result:

You can manually set the cache key from rails console(by typing 'rails c' in command prompt)

```
>> Rails.cache.fetch('answer')
==> "nil"
>> Rails.cache.fetch('answer') {1 + 1}
==> 2
Rails.cache.fetch('answer')
==> 2
```

Consider the following example. An application has a Product model with a class method returning all out of stock items, and an instance method that looks up the product’s price on a competing website. The data returned by these methods would be perfect for low-level caching:

```
# product.rb

def Product.out_of_stock
  Rails.cache.fetch("out_of_stock_products", :expires_in => 5.minutes) do
    Product.all.joins(:inventory).conditions.where("inventory.quantity = 0")
  end
end

def competing_price
  Rails.cache.fetch("/product/#{id}-#{updated_at}/comp_price", :expires_in => 12.hours) do
    Competitor::API.find_price(id)
  end
end
```

I think it will be helpful for you.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be great if you added the source for your answer: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies